# Can a UDP socket hang on "connect" in Python

Tags: python, sockets, dns, udp, python-asyncio

Say I have this program in Python the "connects" a UDP socket:

```py
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.connect(('8.8.8.8', 53))
```

Can the call to connect hang, and so it's better to set a timeout? So something like:

```py
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.settimeout(2)
sock.connect(('8.8.8.8', 53))
```

If so, why? I would have thought connect when using UDP wouldn't connect anything, and at worse it would immediately fail for some reason, rather than hang.

This is in reference to a bug reported in an asyncio Python DNS resolver I wrote: https://github.com/michalc/aiodnsresolver/pull/35 where is *does* seem to hang at connect, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: The socket can hang for some time in connect if the given argument is not an IP address but a hostname, which still need to be resolved to an IP address. And this DNS lookup can be slow. Apart from that connect in UDP is just a local operation which sets the peer address on the socket (as said in the answer), i.e. it should not block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not hang, because it is not actually "connecting" to anything.  UDP is connection-less, after all.  Calling `connect()` on a UDP socket merely creates a static association with the specific peer IP/Port on the local end of the socket, so subsequent sends/receives on the socket will communicate only with that peer.  So there is nothing to hang on.  If you are experiencing a hang on `connect()` on a UDP socket, then that would have to be a bug in your system's underlying socket stack, not with your code.